# Different vimrc by filetype

Tags: gvim, latex, filetype

As the title says: can I use different `_vimrc`s for different programming languages or filetypes? I have to use a lot of different programming languages for lots of different subjects, and for each filetype  I want to toggle the original `_vimrc` and  the individual filetype-specific `_vimrc`. I think all of the filetypes I use are supported by gVim : I mostly use C, C++, Java (Kotlin), and LaTeX.
I'd prefer something I can code without installing plugins, but if I **DO** need plugins, I'd be very grateful for a suggestion or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody's been answering, so I'll just leave what I found for future reference: (I use Windows)
In the $HOME directory, there is a file called `vimfiles`. In that folder, make a `ftplugin` folder, and in *that*, make folders (or `.vim` extension files) with the first word of the name being a specific filetype extension. For instance, `tex` filetype plugins would be named `tex_blahblahblah.vim`. After that, leave the following line in your main `_vimrc` file:

```
filetype plugin on
```